# Multiple steps animation, delay() and queue() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay, jquery-queue

I am trying to animate some text. Fade in, change text, change color, fade out and so on. Unfortunately there seems to be an issue with `delay()` that doesn't work with `html()` or `text()`. So I tried to make it work with `queue()` or `setTimeout()`, but none of it works.
Fadein and fadeout work, but changing text and background-color doesn't work.

Here the two variants I tried without any luck:

Variant 1:

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2x61s3dn/

```
<button>Start Animation</button>

<p>By default, all HTML elements have a static position, and cannot be moved. To manipulate the position, remember to first set the CSS position property of the element to relative, fixed, or absolute!</p>

<div class="eins" style="background:#212f21;height:100px;width:100px;position:absolute;"></div>
<div class="zwei" style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:100px;position:absolute;top:200px;"></div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $(".eins")
        .fadeOut(1000)
        .delay(2000, "my-queue")
        .queue("my-queue", function(next) {
            $(".eins").css("backgroundColor", "red");
            $(".eins").html("hahahhaha");
            next();
        })
        .fadeIn(500)
        .animate({left: '250px'}, 2000);
    $(".zwei").fadeOut(1000).fadeIn(4200).animate({left: '350px'}, 1000);
  });
});
```

Variant 2:

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/37hzt8jk/

```
<button>Start Animation</button>

<p>By default, all HTML elements have a static position, and cannot be moved. To manipulate the position, remember to first set the CSS position property of the element to relative, fixed, or absolute!</p>

<div class="eins" style="background:#212f21;height:100px;width:100px;position:absolute;"></div>
<div class="zwei" style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:100px;position:absolute;top:200px;"></div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $(".eins")
        .fadeOut(1000)
        .delay(2000)
        .setTimeout(function () {
            $(".eins").css("backgroundColor", "red");
            $(".eins").html("hahahhaha");
        }, 5000)
        .fadeIn(500)
        .animate({left: '250px'}, 2000);
    $(".zwei").fadeOut(1000).fadeIn(4200).animate({left: '350px'}, 1000);
  });
});
```

Comment: The second script will never work because `setTimeout` can't be chained as a jQuery method (it gives an error). According to [this page](https://learn.jquery.com/effects/queue-and-dequeue-explained/#custom-queues) a custom `queueName` will only be executed once `.dequeue()` is called. That indeed seems to be working alright [here](https://jsfiddle.net/89jamLwy/).